# What tool can I use to draw flowcharts combined with sequence charts?

Tags: charts, workflow, flowchart

A picture to explains what I mean flowcharts combined with sequence charts (and also the Chinese words there)

So there are 4 participants here (on the top) to collaborate in the event to finish a user action.
But inside each participant there is a flowchat to show different workflows based on user's status and input.

First, I would like to know is there a chart or a formal name existed for such chart ?

Second, I use macOS so I am looking for a mac app or a web app. Hopefully it is a free one.

--- update ----

I finally reached the author and he told me it was Visio Cross-Functional Flowchart! I definitely won't use Visio, it is too expensive.

[image]

Comment: What OS should it run on? Must it be [tag:gratis] – or how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions? What features do you need? Are specific formats for input/output a concern? Please [edit] your question and include those details.

Comment: updated my question. But my first question actually is is there a name for such chart ?

Comment: Looks a bit like swimlanes. Did you have a look at plantuml? See a.o. https://plantuml.com/, http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml, https://github.com/plantuml

Comment: @albert I finally reached the author and he told me it was visio Cross-Functional Flowchart!

Comment: Good to know what was the original source, maybe there are alternatives for visio to reproduce such a picture and otherwise just a drawing package might work as well. It all depends on how often you have to draw such an image and about the flexibility required. My response was just to point to plantuml to draw a similar picture, I never tried such a diagram wit plantuml, but maybe it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

ALL FREE TOOLS:

I like yEd from https://www.yWorks.com (If you like to move your mouse/cursor).

To render DLS I use http://blockdiag.com/en/actdiag/index.html
(PlantUML is complexer: it allows more complexity in your diagrams, but you have to write more code to get the same diagram rendered).

I think this page is very usefull for questions like this:
https://modeling-languages.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://draw.io or https://www.diagrams.net/, they are the same thing with different urls.
This tool gives you complete freedom to merge the most diverse types of diagrams, flowchart and UML. It also allows you to import and save from different locations like Google Drive, OnDrive, Dropbox, GitHub or your device. And the most interesting is the possibility to export in PNG, JPG, SVG, PDF, VSDX, HTML, XML. It is a powerful tool if you want to explore its many features.
I highlight the menu Arrange >> Insert >> Advanced >> PlantUML, which allows diagrams via the command line, and in this case, if you want more information, go to https://plantuml.com